# R: Selecting every two consecutive rows for ddplyr

Tags: r, statistics, plyr, apply, linear-regression

This is my data

```
 Assay Sample Dilution  meanresp number
    1    S     0.25       68.55      1
    1    S     0.50       54.35      2
    1    S     1.00       44.75      3
```

My end goal is to apply a linear regression  to every two consecutive rows and return the slope of that regression using Dilution and meanresp.

The length of the table can vary and i'd prefer not to use for loops as i'm trying to get out of the habit.

I think ddply would be good, but i'm not sure how to select the subset of every two consecutive rows. I thought perhaps there could be a way of saying 'do this for every vector subset of Dilution of length 2?

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect as a result. Something like `diff(meanresp) / diff(Dilution)` (grouped by `Assay` and `Sample`)?

Comment: could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755653/r-how-to-write-a-for-loop-that-reads-every-two-lines-in-a-matrix/26756580#26756580) help you ? (for the selection of every two consecutive rows)

Comment: I'm aiming for something that does this:

ddply(.data=data, .variables='subsets each consecutive 2 rows', .fun='linear model function')

The subsetting is where i'm having trouble. Does this make sense?

Comment: `ddply` splits by columns not rows so you can't use that. Check a way to do it using `lapply` twice below. Essentially you could merge those two as 1 function but I would avoid it as it causes hard-to-read code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how this will be helpful in a linear regression but you could do something like that:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="Assay Sample Dilution  meanresp number
    1    S     0.25       68.55      1
    1    S     0.50       54.35      2
    1    S     1.00       44.75      3")
```

Using `lapply`:

```
> lapply(2:nrow(df), function(x) df[(x-1):x,] )
[[1]]
  Assay Sample Dilution meanresp number
1     1      S     0.25    68.55      1
2     1      S     0.50    54.35      2

[[2]]
  Assay Sample Dilution meanresp number
2     1      S      0.5    54.35      2
3     1      S      1.0    44.75      3
```

In case you want specific columns as well for your consecutive rows you can select them as:

```
> lapply(2:nrow(df), function(x) df[(x-1):x, c('Dilution','meanresp')] )
[[1]]
  Dilution meanresp
1     0.25    68.55
2     0.50    54.35

[[2]]
  Dilution meanresp
2      0.5    54.35
3      1.0    44.75
```

**EDIT**

If you want to perform a linear regression another `lapply` is enough to do it:

```
a <- lapply(2:nrow(df), function(x) df[(x-1):x, c('Dilution','meanresp')] )

b <- lapply(a,function(x) lm(Dilution~meanresp,data=x))

>b
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = Dilution ~ meanresp, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     meanresp  
    1.45687     -0.01761  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = Dilution ~ meanresp, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     meanresp  
    3.33073     -0.05208
```

Or if you just want the slope:

```
b <- lapply(a, function(x) {
                    d <- lm(Dilution~meanresp,data=x)
                    coefficients(summary(d))[2,1]
})

> b
[[1]]
[1] -0.01760563

[[2]]
[1] -0.05208333
```

Comment: This is great, thank-you. It does pretty much exactly what I need (i'll just need to make the list become a dataframe instead showing what dilutions were used).